Calculating the values of the partition function by recursion
Let $p$ denote the partition function of a number. The generating function for $p(n)$ is given by
$1=\Bigl( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n) x^n \Bigr) \Bigl(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2} \Bigr)$
If we consider the coefficients of $x^n$ (for $n>0$), we get
$(*)$ $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k p\bigl(n-\frac{3k^2+k}{2}\bigr)=0$.
This "formaly infinite" sum can be used to calculate $p(n)$, since for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ only finitly many summands are $\neq 0$. This gives us a recursion to calculate $p(n)$.
Now I want to calculate $p(n)$ for  $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I do not really understand how to used the recursion above.
I did try to use this recursion to calculate $p(0)$.
Let $n=0$, then for
$k=-2$ I get $p(5)=0$
$k=-1$ I get $(-1)p(1)=0$
$k=0$ I get $p(0)=0$
$k=1$ I get $(-1)p(2)=0$
$k=2$ I get $p(6)=0$
I don't see how this should help me calculate $p(0)$.
Can someone please explain to me how one can use the recursion $(*)$ to calculate $p(n)$.

First of all, you cannot calculate $p(0)$ from $(*)$ because, as you wrote immediately above, $(*)$ is only true for $n > 0$. In fact $p(0) = 1$ is an initial condition of the recurrence.
For $n > 0$, I'll give an example of how you can calculate $p(n)$ in terms of smaller partition numbers. For $n = 5$ there are four values of $k$ such that $n - \frac{3k^2+k}{2} \ge 0$. These are $-2, -1, 0, 1$. So $(*)$ becomes:
$$\sum_{k \in \left\{-2, -1, 0, 1\right\}} (-1)^kp\left(n - \frac{3k^2+k}{2}\right) = 0$$ or, plugging in the four values of $k$, $$p(0) - p(4) + p(5) - p(3) = 0.$$
Therefore $p(5) = p(4) + p(3) - p(0).$
